# how to Generating an admin controller link in Prestashop using {{url entity= }?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am Migrating a module from 1.6 to 1.7 so i need to remove {$link->getAdminLink('AdminModules')} from my tpl file and i should use {url} helper.

because of this: $link is deprecated (even if it’s still passed to smarty, it will be removed at some point), use {url} helper

here is link: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Migrating+a+module+from+1.6+to+1.7

please help me out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    $stat = PS_ADMIN_DIR;
    $admin_folder = substr(strrchr($stat, "\ "), 1);
    $admin_url =_PS_BASE_URL_.__PS_BASE_URI__.$admin_folder;
    $token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
    $this->context->smarty->assign('token', $token);
    $this->context->smarty->assign('admin_url', $admin_url );
```

that's how i get proper admin controller url. 
hope it will help you.

Comment: but i want {url entity='' '} this type of solution.

Comment: Did anybody find any solution for that? I am also stuck into that problem.

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an admin controller link from in a *.tpl file with the same syntax we use in php, for example:

```html
<a href"{Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink('AdminMymoduleBooksManager', true)}&updateymodule_book=&mymodule_book_id={$id_book}">edit a book in my admin controller<a/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `{$link->getAdminLink('AdminModules')}` by:

- `{url entity='sf' route='admin_module_catalog'}`
- `{url entity='sf' route='admin_module_manage'}`
- or `{url entity='sf' route='admin_module_notification'}`

depending on what tab you want to redirect your users to.

Comment: thanks for your time... 
But I am trying to get this url "/prestashop_1.7.3/admin930wnbkhj/index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=b74676f33d2a210d9a6f0461efb364fd"    And please let me know if there are any documentation available about {url}

Comment: Did anybody find any solution for that? I am also stuck into that problem.

Thanks !!!!